# How to receive KeyPress event in QAbstractScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt

In a customized widget that is derived from `QAbstractScrollArea` I feel unable to receive any keyboard events through the `QAbstractScrollArea::viewportEvent()` handler:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

struct A: public QScrollArea {
    bool viewportEvent(QEvent *e) {
        qDebug() << e;
        return QScrollArea::viewportEvent(e);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    A *a = new A;
    a->viewport()->setFocus();
    a->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Various experimentation with `focusPolicy` and friends on both the `QScrollArea` as well as its `viewport()` did not help either. Curiously enough, the `QScrollArea::event()` handler does receive the key events.

What am I missing?

Comment: It is [recommended](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qabstractscrollarea.html#viewportEvent) to use the specialized event handlers (i.e. `QAbstractScrollArea::keyPressEvent`) instead of `QAbstractScrollArea::viewportEvent`.

Comment: Your citation recomments using specialized event handlers instead of the generic `QAbstractScrollArea::viewportEvent()`. But `QAbstractScrollArea::keyPressEven()` is not mentioned in the list of specialized event handlers. Corristo has the reasoning below.

Comment: No, it is not - that list is not exhaustive. The recommendation encompasses any specialized event handlers, of which `QAbstractScrollArea::keyPressEvent()` is [one](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#reimplemented-protected-functions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you don't receive key events is that the viewport never has focus, since the `QAbstractScrollArea` always sets itself as the focus proxy of the viewport widget. Thus the line `a->viewport()->setFocus()` actually gives the focus to `a`.

In order to receive key events you need to override `QAbstractScrollArea::keyPressEvent` instead of the `viewportEvent`.

Comment: But why, after all? Where do the key events get lost?

Comment: @Kamajii I extended the answer to explain why the viewport itself does not receive key events.

Comment: D'oh. Now this makes sense in that `QAbstractScrollArea` transparently provides the event handlers for the viewport.